# Identity server 4 : how to add Instagram login workflow

Tags: oauth-2.0, instagram, identityserver4

i have read a lot of documentation and i have already implemented IS4 with Twitter, Google, Facebook login/registration workflow successfully.

But i have a lot of problem to implements Instagram.
I have add at startup:

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "Instagram", options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
               options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
               options.SaveTokens = true;
               options.ClientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
               options.ClientSecret = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";
               options.Authority = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/";

               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   NameClaimType = "name",
                   RoleClaimType = "role"
               };
           });
```

I have implements "InstagramAuthProvider" equal than google one in the Example Project of IS4.
From now i can't start the login flow because i have that error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success:
>   404 (Not Found).
>   System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
>
> IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is
>   hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(string
>   address, CancellationToken cancel)
>
> InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration
>   from: '[PII is hidden]'.
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancel)

I really not find something useful about that, possible no one implements Instagram in IS4?
Any suggestion? I'm completely stucked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Instagram authentication provider for ASP.NET Core [here](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Providers):

1. Install [`AspNet.Security.OAuth.Instagram`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OAuth.Instagram/) nuget package
2. Add code:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddInstagram(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                        options.ClientId = "client-Id";
                        options.ClientSecret = "client-secret";
                    });
```

3. Read [Instagram instructions](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) to set the params

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/other-logins?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, i have to Upgrade to Net core 3.1 for use the package otherwise i try a lot to set the login as standard Oauth without success.
With this package i get error like "Oops, an error occurred." after login

Comment: what version do u have? @Inconsapevole

Comment: i use AspNet.Security.OAuth.Instagram 3.1.1 and net core 3.1

Comment: i still work on thi issue. I write on Facebook Developer forum and i don't understand what's wrong.
ref: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1105614206477222/

Comment: question, did you set [OAuth redirect URLS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started#valid-oauth-redirect-uris)? ur return URL must exactly matches one of the base URIs in your list of valid oAuth URIs

Comment: yes i have correctly set the return URL with all my test URL enviroment and a localhost one for testing, all in https beacuse it's a requirment.
Before the login flow redirect (or try to redirect) to my application URI the error appear with a 500 error i have found with fiddler.